# Creating a binary counter in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

How would one go about creating a function *increment*, such that when you give it a binary number the output is the next highest binary number?

**Examples:**

```
• (increment ’(0 0 1))    returns   ’(0 1 0) 
• (increment ’(1 1 0))    returns   ’(1 1 1) 
• (increment ’(1 1 1 1))  returns   ’(0 0 0 0) 
• (increment ’(1 0 1 1 1) returns   ’(1 1 0 0 0)
```

I believe the best way to go about this would be to check if the least significant digit is zero, and change it to 1 if it is. I'm not sure how to actually write that or make it a recursive program.
I've only been programming in scheme for a few weeks so any help, even pseudocode, is helpful.

Comment: I think the third example is wrong, shouldn't that be `'(1 0 0 0 0) ` ? also, your quotes use an incorrect char, it's `'`, not `’`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to handle in little-endian form, so I suggest reversing the list, then reversing the output to put it back in big-endian form.

```
(define (increment lst)
  (define (go lst carry)
    (if (null? lst)
      null
      (let-values (((digit carry^)
                    (case (+ carry (car lst))
                      ((0) (values 0 0))
                      ((1) (values 1 0))
                      ((2) (values 0 1)))))
        (cons digit (go (cdr lst) carry^)))))
  (reverse (go (reverse lst) 1)))
```

As requested, without multiple return values:

```
(define (increment lst)
  (define (go lst carry)
    (if (null? lst)
      null
      (let* ((sum    (+ carry (car lst)))
             (digit  (if (= 1 sum) 1 0))
             (carry^ (if (= 2 sum) 1 0)))
        (cons digit (go (cdr lst) carry^)))))
  (reverse (go (reverse lst) 1)))
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Out of curiosity, can you think of a way to do it without the _carry_ or _let-values_ functions? I'm more used to using the basic cons car and cdr.

Comment: @Lazarus Sure. See above.